# Usage of "no more" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, negation, comparatives

I would need help with the following sentence:

> It may be no more difficult to claim in words a feeling not felt than one that is.

The “no more” is related to the whole sentence or just to the “feeling not felt”?

My understanding (it is incorrect I guess, so I would a little help here):
In other words: *Maybe it is not more difficult to claim in words a feeling we do not feel than one we feel.*

I would need to understand the sentence as a whole.

Also probably I do not translate correctly *may* – can it be “does not have to be” in this context?

Comment: _No more_ is not a constituent here. _More_ is part of the comparative construction _more difficult... than X_, whereas _no_ negates that entire comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"No" in this context means "not any".

The sentence is saying there are two things, and one is *not any more difficult* than the other. The first thing is *to claim in words a feeling that is **not** felt*; the second thing is *to claim in words a feeling that **is** felt*. According to the sentence, neither of those is any more difficult than the other.

Comment: Yes, but I do think saying that something *"**may be** no more X than Y"* strongly implies that whereas it's *definitely not* Y, it's *probably* (but not *definitely*) not X either. As opposed to *"**is** no more X than Y"* which implies that it's *neither*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Good point. I concentrated on the "no more" part, and not the "may" part. So let me rephrase my concluding remark: _According to the (original) sentence, **there is a possibility that** neither of those is any more difficult than the other_.

Comment: Exactly. It's entirely a matter of context how strong that possibility is, of course - but if the possibility is strong enough to say *"it is **probable** that..."*, you'd just phrase it as *"it may **well** be..."*. And even if it's not very likely at all, *"it still **might** be..."*

Comment: ...I must admit I actually have only a hazy idea of what *claiming a feeling that is felt* is supposed to mean, but from the structure of the sentence, I gather OP thinks it's not hard to do. But when it comes to a *feeling that is not felt* I just think we're in the land of bad translations.

Answer (score 3):

This is a ***[Comparative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative)*** construction, identifiable by *more* in one conjunct, and *than* introducing the other. The **no** is simply negation of the entire comparison. As usual, a lot has been left out and switched around by various syntactic processes.

A stab at something like the original structure is the following monstrosity:

- *For `indef` to claim in words a feeling which `indef` does not feel may not be more difficult than for `indef` to claim in words a feeling which `indef` feels.*

The *no more difficult* is a negative idiom appearing in the first conjunct instead of negating the entire comparison.